# How to show Pie Chart , Bar Chart and Line graph in single view in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, bar-chart, pie-chart, linechart

I want to show Graph Charts in iPad ,which is some thing like below image.Please suggest me some idea how to do this ?

I have taken reference from the tutorial [How To Draw Graphs with Core Plot, Part 1 & 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13271/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-2).

here i can see it has used different view controller to perform all three graph.I want it in single view controller only.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create new Project of SingleView Application, drag and drop whats necessary to use core plot also drag these three view controllers in your project.

You got Three View controllers

```
1. CPDPieChartViewController
2. CPDBarGraphViewController
3. CPDScatterPlotViewConntroller
```

make them subclass of of UIView like in .h of them instead of `<UIViewController>` use `<UIView>`

```
1. CPDPieChartView
2. CPDBarGraphView
3. CPDScatterPlotView
```

and inside their implementation file remove code related to UIViewController like method -(void)viewDidAppear and unwanted synthesized objects and add initwithframe method instead.

now inside ur projects main viewcontroller import these three views classes.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  CPDPieChartView *CPDPieChartViewObj=[[CPDPieChartView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectmake(give proper frame)];
[CPDPieChartViewObj initPlot];

CPDBarGraphView *CPDBarGraphViewObj=[[CPDBarGraphView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectmake(give proper frame)];
[CPDBarGraphViewObj initPlot];

CPDScatterPlotView *CPDScatterPlotViewObj=[[CPDScatterPlotView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectmake(give proper frame)];
[CPDScatterPlotViewObj initPlot];

[self.view addSubview:CPDPieChartViewObj];
[self.view addSubview:CPDBarGraphViewObj];
[self.view addSubview:CPDScatterPlotViewObj];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example :
[CompositePlot](https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/browse/examples/CorePlotGallery/src/plots/CompositePlot.m?spec=svnf0dd7863fd8e068802eb7ae259e21dd94f4787be&r=f0dd7863fd8e068802eb7ae259e21dd94f4787be) in [CorePlotGallary](https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/browse/examples/CorePlotGallery/?r=f0dd7863fd8e068802eb7ae259e21dd94f4787be)